# Добавление нескольких зон на карте с помощью Yandex MapKit для android

Tags: android, kotlin, yandexmapkit

Как сделать несколько зон на карте с помощью Yandex MapKit?

Необходимо сделать карту в андроид приложении, как на сайте.
[image: Зоны доставки]

Я не понимаю как сделать хотя бы треугольник(прямоугольник).

Задаю координаты.

```
val pt1 = Point(30.122515, 61.040105)
val pt2 = Point(40.122515, 61.040105)
val pt3 = Point(35.122515, 51.040105)

val polygon = Polygon()
```

но не понимаю как их присвоить полигону.

у polygon нет метода setPoints()

Скорее всего надо использовать какой-то другой класс или метод.

Answer (score 0):

Полигон - это закольцованные координаты. Последняя координата обязана равняться первой - [LinearRing](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/lite/com/yandex/mapkit/geometry/LinearRing.html). А значит для минимального полигона (треугольника) координат должно быть четыре.

Задавать ему координаты надо как ненулевую кольцевую геометрию - [Polygon](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/lite/com/yandex/mapkit/geometry/Polygon.html#_7). Это есть и в [примере](https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yandex/mapkitdemo/MapObjectsActivity.java) Яндекса.

Ну и сам интерфейс - это [PolygonMapObject](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/lite/com/yandex/mapkit/map/PolygonMapObject.html).

Comment: Да я вроде разобрался уже правда плохо помню. Polygon не нужен метод setPoints(), он задаётся сразу например так:
```kotlin  
val polygon = Polygon(LinearRing(innerPoints), listOf(LinearRing(externalPoints)))  
            val polygonMapObject: PolygonMapObject = mapObjects!!.addPolygon(polygon)
```